# How do I display the full text on the Qtabbar label?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtabwidget, qstylesheet

I want to display like picA but now it's like picB ,

[image]

here is my stylesheet

```
QTabBar:tab {  
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    color: #969696;
    font: 9pt "Courier New";
    padding: 15px;
}
QTabBar:tab:selected {  
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 9pt "Courier New";
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You can set width for tab bar `width: 100px; `

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, the tabs always expand to fit the text and padding. What platform are you on? Are you applying any other stylesheets?

Comment: I use win7, if I use default font size and type,it's normal , and I try to find how to set content margin, but I don't find the answer , therefore ,maybe  should I use delegate to do that?